# Using Knex/Postgresql What Does This Mean? "error: column "*" does not exist"

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I had a project that I shelved for awhile, but recently I dusted it off and updated all the NPM packages.  Now when I try to do anything database related (using Knex/Postgresql) I get the error:

```
error: column "*" does not exist
```

This will happen with a seemingly harmless query like:

```
select "*" from "some_table" where "id" = $1
```

If I run that query directly against the DB:

```
select * from "some_table" where "id" = 1;
```

it works fine.  But no matter what I try with knex, whether it's running a regular query or trying to reset my whole database, I keep getting that seemingly nonsensical error.

Can anyone explain what it means?

Comment: knex.select().table('books') will result in `select *` - even though this was not your question, ;]

Comment: `"*"` is something different than `*`

Comment: Please tell also what kind of code you write for knex to generate that query. It is impossible to tell otherwise why generation of that kind of query happen.

Comment: Part of the problem is that I don't know which code exactly is the problem: all of the line in the stacktrace are node_modules or system calls, and again I get the error both when trying to run the site or when trying to run migrations (and my site has many queries involving this table).  But thanks to the answer, I can now at least start tracking it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The double quotes around the `*` cause it not to be interpreted as “all columns”, but as a column with that very name.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why my code went from selecting `*` to selecting `"*"`, just from an npm update, but apparently that's what happened, and I can work from there.  Thanks!

Comment: Just a follow-up for anyone else reading this later: I figured out that the problem was that Knex went from using the syntax `.select('*')` to create a `SELECT * FROM ...` clause, to a syntax of just `.select()`.  Making that change in your code should fix the issue.